# Aggregate Portfolio Simulation vs. Underlying Assets

Tags: stochastic-processes, multivariate

Background: I am currently implementing a correlated Monte Carlo simulation model using Cholesky decomposition to create the sampling distribution.

Question: What is the difference between creating and sampling an aggregate distribution of correlated assets and simply creating a univariate simulation based on the portfolio level expected return and volatility, as is seen in MVO?

*Sorry if the questions been answered already, I'm relatively new to this stack exchange and couldn't find anything specifically answering this question*